# PHP Stripos Check for two Words in a URL string

Tags: php, url, stripos

I'm currently using PHP Stripos OK to look for a word (parrots) is present within a URL.

However I now need to check that 2 words (green and parrots) are present in a URL, i.e. they must both be present.

Here's the current code:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-parrots') !== false) 
        {echo '<div class="clear"></div><a href="http://www.example.com/parrots/" class="btn"> >> Parrots</a>';}
```

The above works well.

For two words I've tried:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-green','-parrots') !== false) 
        {echo '<div class="clear"></div><a href="http://www.example.com/green-parrots/" class="btn"> >> Green Parrots</a>';}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check for each individually.  The function you're using doesn't work in the way you've invented.  Take a look at the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 1):

with `stripos()` you have `needle`, `haystack` and offset

you would be better off looking for

```
if ( (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-green') !== false) && (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-parrot') !== false) )
```

you can use `&&` (and) or `||` (or) depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Just use two `stripos` calls:

```
<?php
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-parrots') !== false &&
    stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-green') !== false) {
    // ...
}
```